# Is any element of a vector space E uniquely written as a linear combination of the elements of a system of generators of E?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read that if {$x_{1}$,...,$x_{n}$}is a basis of E over K,then every element u of E is uniquely written in the form u=$a_{1}x_{1}$+...+$a_{n}x_{n}$where $a_{1},...,a_{n}$ belong K.

Is it the same for a system of generators??I mean does the word "uniquely" remain valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO.

$\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$ is a set of generators of $\Bbb R^2$

Then $(1,2)=1.(1,0)+2.(0,1)+0.(1,1)$

$(1,2)=(-1).(1,0)+0.(0,1)+2.(1,1)$